# what does this notation mean <x1,x2>?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, latex, notation, convex-optimization

I was reading about k-strong convexity and came a across an equation like this

f(x_1) >= f(x_2) + <\Delta f(x_2), x_1-x_2> + (k/2)*(||x_1-x_2||^2)

Could some one explain what the notation <> means?

Sorry for the errors with latex.

Comment: <x, y> is a dot product. Exact equation depends on the particular dot product, but the most common one is SUM_i x_i y_i

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't cover any topics relevant to this site (as described in the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)).

Answer (score 1):

```
<x,y> is the dot (scalar) product of x and y 

<x,y> = y'*x
```

as y' is the tronspose of y, for more you can cheek [scalar product](https://people.math.osu.edu/husen.1/teaching/571/ch5.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

I think that these part of quantum mechanics, especially matrix mechanics
< x1 is called bra vector and x2> is called as the ket vector. Please check with quantum mechanics book. Please check the book by Dirac on quantum mechanics.